# password recovery while os is running

Tags: password-recovery

When I start my PC , then ubuntu is not asking for password. But when I want to install any software , at that time, it is asking for password, Therefore I lost my password. How to recover my password?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can recover your password. Boot into single user mode on your PC

- Interrupt your PC as it boots by pressing the arrow keys
- Select your OS and tap letter **a** on your key board.
- Space and append 1 at the end of the **rhgb quiet**
- Press enter and reboot and then type in **passwd** and you shall be prompted for a password.
- Type in your new password and there you go. You have your new password succesfully set.
- Now reboot and login with your new password.

Try that and let me know how it works out.

Comment: I use RedHat so rh means redHat